# Как правильно: суперЭВМ или супер-ЭВМ?

Tags: орфография

Подскажите, как правильно писать: суперЭВМ или супер-ЭВМ? 
У Розенталя через дефис, в орфографическом словаре и на Грамоте - слитно.
Объяснения про дефис понятны: перед именем собственным.

Как писать будем, товарищи?!

Comment: Татьяна, а о каком имени собственном идет речь? ЭВМ - это  аббревиатура(сокр.: электронно-вычислительная машина), слово с нарицательным значением, хотя среди аббревиатур встречаются и имена собственные (СНГ, БАМ).

Answer (score 5):

Мне более по душе старое написание. Ну не принимает взгляд мой прописной буквы в середине слова. Тогда логично и полМосквы писать, а не пол-Москвы. Ведь мы дефис ставим именно чтобы отделить прописную букву с в середине слова от строчной. Или тогда признать правильной аббревиатуру "эвм" и писать "суперэвм".  Кстати,  такие написания тоже встречаются.

Answer (score 1):

слушай Розенталя - он плохого не посоветует ;)

Answer (score 0):

ПОНАБЛЮДАЕМ ЗА СЛОВОМ «СУПЕР»

Если ориентироваться на толковые словари, то  СУПЕР является приставкой и во всех случаях пишется слитно: суперцемент, суперкласс, суперобложка, супермодный, суперсовременный.  Однако в современном языке СУПЕР стало употребляться и как самостоятельное слово в значении высшей оценки, в том числе в роли сказуемого, например: «книга просто супер».

Также  слово СУПЕР начинает проявлять самостоятельные признаковые свойства, особенно в области  нестандартных написаний, в том числе в сочетаниях с  аббревиатурами. Орфография здесь неустоявшаяся,  и фактически применяются все три формы: слитно, раздельно, дефис,  например: игра "Супер Твистер", тариф «Супер МТС», портал Супер-Инфо, суперЭВМ и супер-ЭВМ.  Дефис не противоречит нормам русской орографии  (сравнить: гала-концерт), раздельное написание копирует английский порядок слов.

Единственный вариант, выпадающий из общей картины,  – это   «суперЭВМ», который совершенно несвойственен русскому письму, лучше писать это сочетание через дефис. Также  неплохо смотрелся бы вариант «супер ЭВМ» с раздельным написанием, который ближе к современным формам.

Comment: София!
Недавно моя знакомая была на конференции по русскому языку. Я просила её задать вопрос про это слово. Вот к чему пришли в итоге дискуссии.
Вариант «суперЭВМ» встречается чаще, фиксируется словарями (Русский орфографический словарь/Российская академия наук. Институт русского языка им. В.В. Виноградова – М., 2007). Кроме того, такое написание встречается в нормативных правовых актах Правительства Российской Федерации.
В связи с этим предлагается придерживаться слитного написания: «суперЭВМ».

Comment: Посмотрела в Грамоте-ру. В орфографическом словаре - суперЭВМ, в толковом - супер-ЭВМ. Вообще говоря, мы живем в эпоху перемен, когда невозможное становится возможным.А есть еще похожие слова, для которых такая запись является нормой? Нельзя же одному слову предоставлять исключительное право.

Answer (score 0):

Уважаемые София и Илья!

Дело в том, что нам
 нужно было чётко, однозначно определить, как писать это слово, потому что такое написание будет рекомендовано всем предприятиям нашей отрасли.
Не доверять консультантам Правительства Российской Федерации, которые проверяют нормативные акты на предмет правописания, нет оснований.
Так что, будем придерживаться слитного написания.

Comment: Тогда пишем слитно, все другие написания следует считать неправильными. Остается только объяснить решение. Будем считать, что суперЭВМ - это термин, а у терминов свои особенности и привилегии. Они должны писаться по возможности слитно, строго сохранять одну форму написания, при этом в отношении их могут применяться   особые (исключительные)правила. Также учтем, что суперкомпьютер и суперЭВМ - это синонимы, и для них желательна одинаковая форма записи.